# How to check if a port is open with the least number of bytes

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, nmap

I have a Raspberry pi connected to a cell modem and am looking for a way to check if a single port on a public IP is open or closed using the least amount of data possible.  There seem to be tons of different ways to check if a port is open but I have not been able to find any posts that aim to minimize data usage at the same time.

I am only looking at bytes transmitted and so far the lowest I have gotten a single request is 152 bytes using the following nmap command:

```
nmap -sT -Pn -n -v 8.8.8.8 -p 5000 --packet-trace --max-retries 0
```

Does anyone know of a method that would use less?  Ideally one that could be implemented using python2.7.

Comment: The 152 bytes consisted of what exactly?

Comment: @EJP I am not sure, I was using jnettop to monitor network traffic and it said I sent 152 bytes to my target IP address.